# Bigquery resources exceeded during query execution, quota?

Tags: google-bigquery

With Google BigQuery, I'm running a query with a group by and receive the error, "resources exceeded during query execution".

Would an increased quota allow the query to run?

Any other suggestions?

```
SELECT
ProductId,
StoreId, 
ProductSizeId,
InventoryDate as InventoryDate,
avg(InventoryQuantity) as InventoryQuantity
FROM BigDataTest.denorm
GROUP EACH BY   
ProductSizeId,
InventoryDate,
ProductId,
StoreId;
```

The table is around 250GB, project # is 883604934239.

Comment: It seems there's a problem with GROUP EACH BY, see the other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348898/bigquery-response-too-large-to-return-when-using-group-each-by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335574/response-too-large-to-return-with-limit-1

Comment: Yes, this seems like a bug with GROUP EACH BY. Investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of reducing the data involved and recent updates to BigQuery, this query now runs.

```
where ABS(HASH(ProductId) % 4) = 0
```

Was used to reduce the 1.3 Billion rows in the table (% 3 still failed).

With the test data set it gives "Error: Response too large to return in big query" which can be handled by writing the results out to a table. Click Enable Options, 'Select Table' (and enter a table name), then check 'Allow Large Results'.